# How to create a template column in Telerik silverlight RadGridView?

Tags: silverlight, gridview

I am using Telerik Silverlight RadGridView to display instrument prices. There is a column called Price which shows the price of an instrument. Now, I want to display a red arrow or a green arrow whenever the price goes up or down.

I can do this easily in asp.net Telerik. But, not sure how to acheive this functionality using Telerik Silverlight controls.

Please help.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the approach from this blog post:
http://blogs.telerik.com/pavelpavlov/posts/10-05-20/displaying_live_streaming_data_with_radgridview_for_silverlight_and_wpf.aspx